# Invoke-RestMethod URL with backslash

Tags: rest, powershell

I've found a lot of information about dealing with forward slashes in `Invoke-RestMethod`, but I can't seem to find anything about handling backslashes.  I know they should be avoided, but I've got some constraints to work within where I can't change the information.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Invoke-RestMethod "http://blah.blah.net/api/Reporting/$ServerName" -Method Get
```

It works fine on other instances, but this time `$ServerName` will have a value like "Server1\SQLserv".  I've tried using `$ServerName -replace "\", "\\\"` and other variants of that, as well as substituting in `%5C` (URL escape character) for the backslash.  Nothing seems to be working.  Anyone encountered (and solved!) this?

EDIT: Here's the specific error I'm getting.  Note that it does work fine for other servers I'm querying against, despite saying the service has been removed:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its
name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod "http://blah.blah.net/api/Report ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: Looks like a server-side issue to me. Also, `Server1\SQLserv` isn't a servername, really. It's the name of an SQL Server instance. Are you sure your web application actually accepts this as input?

Comment: I agree, it seems to be a server side issue.  At fault, really, is the name of the server.  Yes, the web app should be able to accept this as input.  The more I look at this and investigate, the more I think I should find another way to accomplish this.  Maybe even messing with database entries to avoid having to utilize a backslash at all.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

-Replace is a regex replace method. You could try using the string replace method which will only replace literal characters.

```
$ServerName.Replace('\','/')
Invoke-RestMethod "http://blah.blah.net/api/Reporting/$ServerName" -Method Get
```

Now if you also need to remove the 'SQLserv' string, I would do this:

```
$Server = Split-Path -Path $ServerName -Parent
Invoke-RestMethod "http://blah.blah.net/api/Reporting/$Server" -Method Get
```

Comment: Great information, thanks.  I'm still having the issue, but I think I'm going to try a different approach.  Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

As [Ansgar mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396302/invoke-restmethod-url-with-backslash/37397503#comment62302782_37396302), this is probably a server error. However, I would recommend to use the [EscapeUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspxe0Iw&bvm=bv.122676328,d.bGg) function to escape your `uri`:

```
$ServerName = "Server1\SQLserv"
$myUri = [System.Uri]::EscapeUriString("http://blah.blah.net/api/Reporting/$ServerName") 
Invoke-RestMethod $myUri -Method Get
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Still having the issue, but this is probably something I can use in the future!  As I mention in a main thread comment, I think I'm going to find another way to accomplish this.